# Using ServiceStack's ServiceClient

Tags: servicestack, serviceclient

I got recommended in another thread that I should use ServiceClient when using 
a ServiceStack API.

I would like to create a template function that can post any type of objects like this:

```
public Post2<T>(object: T, url: string, httpOptions)
{
try
{
  var client = new JsonServiceClient(`${environment.apiEndpoint}` + url)
  client.headers = httpOptions;
  client.post<T>(object);

}
catch(e)
{

}
```

}

The problem is that it tells me that "argument of type T is not assignable to parameter of type IReturn.

typescript-ref http://techstacks.io generated the following DTO's (for this purpose)

```
// @Route("/Equipments", "POST")
export class CreateEquipment
{
    public name: string;
}

// @Route("/Equipments/{Name}", "GET")
export class GetEquipment implements IReturn<Equipment>
{
    public name: string;
    public createResponse() { return new Equipment(); }
    public getTypeName() { return 'GetEquipment'; }
 }

 // @Route("/Equipments", "GET")
 export class GetEquipments implements IReturn<Equipment[]>
{
    public createResponse() { return new Array<Equipment>(); }
    public getTypeName() { return 'GetEquipments'; }
}

// @Route("/Equipments/{Name}", "DELETE")
export class DeleteEquipment
{
    public name: string;
}
```

I tried to use the following code to create the Post request.

```
var request = new CreateEquipment();
request.name = equipment.name;
var client = new JsonServiceClient(environment.apiEndpoint);
var response = await client.post(request);
```

This gives an error in the VS17;   argument of type 'CreateEquipment' is not assignable to parameter of type 'IReturn<{}>'.Property createResponse is missing in type'CreateEquipment'

Which I presume means that I am missing something in my ServiceModel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ServiceStack's [TypeScript Service Client](https://docs.servicestack.net/typescript-add-servicestack-reference#typescript-serviceclient) should only be constructed with the **BaseUrl** for where your ServiceStack Host is located, or if you don't specify an argument it will use `/` by default:

```
var client = new JsonServiceClient(environment.apiEndpoint);
```

You also need to use it with the [TypeScript generated DTOs](http://docs.servicestack.net/typescript-add-servicestack-reference#simple-command-line-utilities-for-typescript) from your ServiceStack Service which you can generate by installing the `@servicestack\cli` npm util:

```
$ npm install -g @servicestack/cli
```

Then using it to generate your Server DTOs from the **BaseUrl** (should be the same as environment.apiEndpoint):

```
$ typescript-ref http://example.org
```

Then you can use it to send populated Request DTOs:

```
var request = new MyRequest();
var response = await client.post(request);
```

Note your ServiceStack Services should be annotated with the `IReturn<T>` (or IReturnVoid) interface marker specifying the Services Response DTO.

You can also [make API Requests using URLs](http://docs.servicestack.net/typescript-add-servicestack-reference#making-api-requests-with-urls), but you'll need to specify the **Response DTO** Type it returns, e.g:

```
client.get<GetTechnologyResponse>("/technology", { Slug: "ServiceStack" })
```

Comment: I just have to say, even thought I am not supposed too, but that solution was really nice! Keep up the good work!

Comment: I spoke to early.. The solution is still really nice, but I get argument of type "CreateEquipment is not assignable to parameter of type IReturn<T> property createResponse is missing in CreateEquipment" I presume that this means that I am missing something in the class on the server.

Comment: @AtleKristiansen please update your question with the generated DTOs, your client code and full error details

Comment: @AtleKristiansen your CreateEquipment Request DTO needs an `IReturn<T>` interface marker, rerun your server then you can run `ts-ref` without any arguments to update your TypeScript DTOs.

Comment: Should I create a DTO for the IReturn<T>?

Comment: @AtleKristiansen No it should be whatever Response DTO your Service is returning.

Comment: I see, I currently return two types HttpResult and HttpError (as per suggestion by you earlier) should I create a more general one? I.E         
        public Equipment Equipment { get; set; }
        public ResponseStatus ResponseStatus { get; set; }

Comment: @AtleKristiansen it should be whatever the Response Body is, i.e. the response in `HttpResult`. It should never be `HttpResult` or `HttpError` - they're internal server decorator classes. If your Service doesn't return anything (i.e. just throws a HttpError) than you should use `IReturnVoid` instead of `IReturn<T>`.

Comment: has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: The value of the 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header in the response must not be the wildcard '*' when the request's credentials mode is 'include'.

Comment: Should I disabled the credentials mode on the server?

Comment: @AtleKristiansen You need to [Enable CORS](https://docs.servicestack.net/corsfeature) which doesn’t sound like you can use a wildcard host so you’ll need to specify an origin whitelist, see docs for an example. This could potentially also be the cause of your Angular HTTP client issues.

Comment: I was able to post using the HTTP Client, but I will take a look at this tomorrow. Thanks for the great assist.

Comment: I added the whitelisting, but now I get "Request header field headers is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers in preflight response." Instead, is there some options by default in the JsonServiceClient?

Comment: @AtleKristiansen you have an issue with your CorsFeature configuration, do you have anything else in allowedHeaders besides Content-Type?

Comment: allowedHeaders: "Content-Type, Authorization". What more do I need?

Comment: @AtleKristiansen The `JsonServiceClient` only uses `Content-Type` by default or `Authorization` if you're using a BearerToken or Basic Auth, so there should be nothing else needed for the `JsonServiceClient`. It's not clear what header it's having an issue with, perhaps if you open a new question showing the full HTTP Request/Response headers being sent (using something like [Fiddler](https://www.telerik.com/fiddler))

Comment: Done, I cannot see any data capture between the webservice and the API tho..https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55209512/cors-configuration-issues-when-using-servicestacks-jsonserviceclient